# Custom TransformationFunction in Graphics? GeometricTransformation::nonaffine error

Tags: geometric-transform

There are many functions in Mathematica, which return expressions with `TransformationFunction` head, for example [RotationTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationTransform.html). Unfortunately, there is no PerspectiveTransform amongst them.

How to create custom transformation functions in general? There is no explanation in docs. It is only said that "TransformationFunction works like Function." what does it mean? That writing `TransformationFunction` is just writing a `Function`?

Also it is said that when possible "matrix forms for transformations can be obtained from TransformationFunction objects using TransformationMatrix."

Can I have some samples of custom TransformationFunction with and without matrix?

**UPDATE**

If I provide my transformation (homogenous) matrix it produces "nonaffine" error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Now trying to form transformation via `LinearFractionalTransform` and effect ios the same

[image]

Comment: have a look at FindGeometricTransform and the Transformation options

Comment: Ok, `FindGeometricTransform` can return perspective transform. But what about generating custom one?

Comment: Just provide the transformation matrix as an argument, e.g. `custom = TransformationFunction[Array[Plus,{4,4}]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods does not work; see my update

Comment: The problem in your update is with `GeometricTransformation`, which can only deal with affine transformations.

Comment: @SimonWoods where is it written?

Comment: I inferred it from the error message - it appears to be missing from the documentation.

Comment: It is in the documentation: "GeometricTransformation[g,{m,v}] effectively applies an affine transform to g."

Comment: @bills, I see what you mean, but Suzan is using the first form: `GeometricTransformation[g, tfun]` and it isn't clear that `tfun` must be affine.

Comment: Also it is not clear if it is an error or a warning, since some drawing is produced nevertheless

Comment: Yes, it effectively sets the bottom row of the matrix to `{0,0,1}` to make the transformation affine. It would be better if the message explained that, so you know that what you get out is not what you asked for.

Comment: @Simon Woods -- I have updated my answer to reflect the current state of the discussion -- if you put up an answer I will happily delete mine.

Comment: @bills, I think your latest edit sums up the situation nicely. I see no reason to replace it with one of mine that would just say the same thing :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can define any matrix as a transformation in `LinearFractionalTransform`:

```
t = LinearFractionalTransform[{{1, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 3}, {1, 1, 9}}]
```

However, this can only be applied to a geometric object using

```
 Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], t]]
```

if the matrix is affine.

The subtlety is that the `TransformationFunction` itself need not be affine, but that `GeometricTransformation` requires an affine transformation. In 2D, the distinction is that an affine transformation represents a mapping A.x+b where A is a 2 by 2 matrix and b is a 2 by 1 vector. These six numbers become the top two rows of the Transformation matrix, and the bottom row is {0,0,1}. `GeometricTransformation` gives an error if this is not the case. In the comments, Simon Woods points out that after issuing the error, `GeometricTransformation` then calculates the output as if the bottom row were {0,0,1}, effectively truncating the bottom row. This behavior is alluded to in the help file, which says: `GeometricTransformation[g,{m,v}]` effectively applies an affine transform to g." Apparently, this same restriction applies to the form `` `GeometricTransformation[g, tfn] `` as well.

If you wish to transform images through your non-affine mapping, there is the function
`ImagePerspectiveTransformation` which allows application of *any* matrix transformation to a 2D image. The first example in the help file shows a transformation with a matrix that is clearly non-affine. So if you have an image to manipulate, or if you are willing to rasterize your current object, this can be done straightforwardly.

Comment: You used different values and I don't understand how this relates with my case.

Comment: Ah, you meant that to get transformation represented by arbitrary homogenous matrix it should be passed to `LinearFractionalTransform`, not to `TransformationFunction`?

Comment: @Suzan, yes. ${}$

Comment: @J. M. it also does not work

Comment: @J. M., `LinearFractionalTransform` just passes the matrix through to `TransformationFunction`. The real issue here is that `GeometricTransformation` can't handle non-affine transformations.

Comment: @Simon, oh I forgot that tiny restriction...

Comment: @J. M., apparently so did WRI when they wrote the manual...