# Plots using TextAlignment with SwatchLegend to left align multi-line items

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, legending

I have Legends that stretch over multi-lines and the only way I can get them left aligned is by adding white space to the end of the legend item. Does anyone know if there is a way to use TextAlignment with [SwatchLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SwatchLegend.html)?

```
gJ = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 12}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[
     SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0], RGBColor[0., 0.329412, 0.], 
       RGBColor[0.619608, 0.25098, 1.], 
       RGBColor[0, 1, 1]}, {"it ends up centred", "but ", 
       "fox jumped over two lines that I want to \nalign to the left",
        "A quick brown"}, 
      LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[]}], 
        Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[]}], 
        Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[]}], 
        Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[]}], 
        Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[]}]}, 
      LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn", LegendMarkerSize -> 16, 
      LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 18}, 
      Spacings -> {0.5, 0.25}], {0.4167, 0.7701}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question. Is it also an issue for `LineLegend`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is to use `TextCell` only there you can have full control over the text:

```
lbl = TextCell["fox jumped over two lines that I want to\nalign to the left", 
         TextAlignment -> Left];
```

So:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 12}, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
             PlotLegends -> {Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red}, {lbl}, 
                                     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 18},
                                     LegendMarkerSize -> 16], 
                             {0.4167, 0.7701}]}]
```

[image]

Related usage of `TextJustification` on StarWars theme: [47273](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47273/5478)

Comment: Since I am programmatically generating the Legend command with a GUI your answer will be the easiest way. Thanks.

Comment: @WolframFan I'm glad you find it useful. It looks simple but it took me a lot of health to realise that painless text formatting without `TextCell` is impossible :P

Comment: Would `Pane` work as well? @WolframFan -this should probably be automated in the underlying legend-creating code if possible.

Comment: @Verbeia Yes, this can be done multiple ways. But I wanted to advertise `TextCell` since you can't use e.g.  `TextJustification` without this. So we can use `TextCell` to text formatting or we can use shorter ways but not general.

Comment: @Kuba of course, but isn't  [`Alignment` and `Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pane.html) equivalent to this?

Comment: @Verbeia Let's go to chat :)

Answer (score 5):

Adapting an example in the docs you could do it this way:

```
table[pairs_] := Grid[pairs, BaseStyle -> {TextAlignment -> Left}, Alignment -> 
{Left, Automatic}]
```

Then use `LegendLayout -> table,` to give you:

[image]

**Edit**

To reverse it just use `Reverse`:

```
reversetable[pairs_] := Grid[Reverse@pairs, BaseStyle -> {TextAlignment -> Left},    
Alignment -> {Left, Automatic}]
```

`LegendLayout -> reversetabletable,`

[image]

Comment: @WolframFan This one might be easier to automate, since the value of the `LegendLayout` Option can be set in any underlying package.

Comment: I just realised you can't reverse this. Notice that the OP had `LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"`

Comment: @Verbeia to reverse it why not use `Reverse` :)