# Text beside image

Tags: image, text

I have a lot of text in my Notebook (Format>Style>Text), and I would like to have the full width text, then insert an image on the left, and have the text continue down the right side of the image, then continue full width afterwards. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might help https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47823/1056

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky to automate, but might help.

```
text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], {226, 1252}];
columntext1 = StringTake[text, 450];
columntext2 = StringDrop[text, 408];
column1 = 
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {170, 240}], Black, 
    Inset[TextCell[columntext1, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, 
      TextJustification -> 1], {0, 240}, {Left, Top}, {170, 
      Automatic}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 170}, {0, 240}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", 
     FontSize -> 14}];

column2 = 
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {330, 179}], Black, 
    Inset[TextCell[columntext2, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, 
      TextJustification -> 1], {0, 179}, {Left, Top}, {330, 
      Automatic}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 330}, {0, 179}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", 
     FontSize -> 14}];

image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Couple2"}];
clippedimage = 
  Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {150, 218}], 
    Inset[image, {95, 100}, {Center, Center}, {260, 260}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 218}}, ImageSize -> 150];

Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {330, 400}],
  Inset[clippedimage, {75, 290}, {Center, Center}, {150, 218}],
  Inset[column1, {245, 280}, {Center, Center}, {170, 240}],
  Inset[column2, {165, 85}, {Center, Center}, {330, 179}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 330}, {0, 400}}, ImageSize -> 330]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
GridBox[{{cat, 
    "xxxx lkajsdflkj sdflkj aldkfj laskjdf lkasjd flkjas dflkja \
sdlfkj asdlfkj aslkdjf alskdjf "}, {" ", " "}}, 
  ColumnWidths -> {8, 15}, ColumnLines -> True, 
  GridFrame -> True] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

Comment: Well, going with the simplest first, I had to add RowAlignments -> {Top, Top} to get the text to start at the top, then Text[text] instead of just text to clean it up, but I still cant get rid of the indentations of all lines but the top. Also, I see \n's where there should be returns.